# Is a JOB card necessary?

Tags: jcl

I guess Job Cards are such like global attributes of a Java Class. In my job, I never used these job cards attributes. So job card is necessary in a job ? Could you please look at the job card below and tell me if that's required and why I need it ?

Best Regards

```
     //BJ03H03 JOB (BBO09272,0000),                                                  
     //             'NHS-STAT  $',                                                   
     //             USER=BPB,                                                        
     //             SCHENV=HDZ2PO,                                                   
     //             CLASS=E,                                                         
     //             TIME=270,                                                        
     //             MSGCLASS=2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is and isn't required on a job card will be system/installation dependent. The minimum requirement is that a JOB statement with a JOBNAME exist. i.e. `//JOBNAME JOB` *(an EXEC statement is also required)*

However, your installation will likely require other parameters, it may implement defaults. In short you need to either speak to the system programmers or alternately experiment by omitting parameters (this latter method could end up resulting in discussions with the Systems Programmers (perhaps angry ones)).

> The system is designed to enable users to perform many types of job
>   control in many ways. To allow this flexibility, only two job entry
>   tasks are required:
>
> Identification: The job must be identified in the jobname field of a JOB statement.
>   Execution: The program or procedure to be executed must be named in a PGM or PROC parameter on an EXEC statement.
>
> Therefore, the following statements are the minimum needed to perform
>   a job control task:

```
//jobname  JOB
//         EXEC  {PGM=program-name   }
                    {PROC=procedure-name}
                    {procedure-name}`
```

As from [Task Charts z/OS MVS JCL Reference SA23-1385-00](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ieab600/iea3b6_Task_Charts.htm) which wouldn't be the worst starting place to find out more.

Comment: Just a point of trivia...the TSO "SUBMIT" command automatically generates a JOB card, based on fields from your TSO account definition. This is handy when you're writing scripts that submit JCL, but you don't know what to specify for job class, account codes, etc etc etc.